# Laravel-Excel: Error in excel Import using ExcelFile injections & Import Handlers

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel

I am using [Laravel-Excel package](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/) in my project.I am following all steps mentioned in [Laravel-Excel Documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#basics) and all things are working perfectly.

**Code is Working:-**

**ExamsController.php**

```
public function uploadExamList(Request $request)
{
    // Handle the import ExamList
    //$examList->handleImport();

    $file = \Input::file('exam_file');
    \Excel::load($file, function($reader) {

        $results = $reader->get();
        //do what you want
    });
}
```

Further,I have tried to implemented [ExcelFile injections & Import Handlers](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#injection) as mentioned in Laravel-Excel documentation and here code is crashed.

**Code not Working:-**

**ExamsController.php**

```
public function uploadExamList(ExamListImport $examList)
{
    // Handle the import ExamList
    $examList->handleImport();
}
```

**ExamListImport.php**

```
<?php

class ExamListImport extends \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ExcelFile {

    public function getFile()
    {
        // Import a user provided file
        $file = \Input::file('exam_file');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        //newfilename
        $newFileName = \Auth::user()->name ."_" .date("YmdHis",time()) . "_". preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fileName) ;
        //destination
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/assets/files/';
        //file with full storage path
        $fileWithFullPath = $destinationPath . $newFileName;

        $file->move($destinationPath, $newFileName);

        return $fileWithFullPath;
    }

}
```

**ExamListImportHandler.php**

```
<?php

class ExamListImportHandler implements \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ImportHandler {

    public function handle($import)
    {
        \Excel::load($import, function($reader) {
            $results = $reader->get();
            var_dump($results);
        });

        return $reader;
    }

}
```

**Error:-**
ErrorException in LaravelExcelReader.php line 735:
realpath() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think '$$reader' should be '$reader' over here :

ExamListImportHandler.php

class ExamListImportHandler implements \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\ImportHandler {

```
public function handle($import)
{
    \Excel::load($import, function($reader) {
        $results = $$reader->get();
        var_dump($results);
    });

    return $reader;
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for confusion.That was my typo. Corrected.